# VS compiler error C2752 ("more than one partial specialization matches") in STL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

Somehow I like these "shortest" programs showing a (fundamental?) problem. When testing some template code in VS2008 this error showed up (it has also been confirmed for VS2010 and VS2012, see below):

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xmemory(225) : error C2752: 'std::_Ptr_cat_helper<_T1,_T2>' : more than one partial specialization matches the template argument list
>
> ```
>    with
>    [
>        _T1=const float (**),
>        _T2=const float (**)
>    ]
> ```

I could boil down the problem to the following three lines:

```
#include <vector>
typedef float TPoint[3];
std::vector<TPoint const*> points; // error C2752
```

Note that the following is all ok

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
typedef float TPoint[3];
// these similar usages of TPoint are all ok:
std::vector<TPoint*> points; // no error
TPoint const* points1[2];
std::list<TPoint const*> points2;
```

I tried to fix xutility by supplying additional template spezializations for struct _Ptr_cat_helper - without luck. Any ideas what goes wrong? Or how to work around without loosing the `const`?

Comment: Don't have a VS install in front of me, but it works with GCC. You may have found a bug in their standard lib.

Comment: Upgrading VS is currently not possible: we depend on dlls (using MFC components) from other groups ... But it would be great to hear if the three lines above compile on VS2010

Comment: Sorry, it does not compile, which is why I removed that comment. :/ It's not entirely clear what the element of the vector should be, though. A pointer to an array of three elements of const floats?

Comment: The elements of the vector are `float**` in this case. I am writing template code that can deal with any 3d point type (supporting a certain interface). The points are allocated only once, but are referenced in several containers (different sorting), hence the `TPoint const*`. When testing with one of the simplest 3d point types `float TPoint[3]` I get the above error.

Comment: @Xeo so even VS2012 shows that error?

Comment: I tried your example code on VS08 and stumbled upon the types mentioned there, in contrast to the types printed by `typeid().name`. Compare `const float (**)` in the error to `const float (* *)[3]`, which is the result of `typeid(TPoint const* *).name()`. The additional indirection is added by the vector's allocator. Maybe this is even more a compiler bug than a library bug?

Comment: This look like a bug. It might be either a compiler bug or a library bug; further investigation would be required to find the root cause.  Since this bug is reproducible using Visual C++ 2012, please open a bug on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) and post a link here in a comment so that others may find it.  If you do not care to open a bug, please let me know and I will open one to make sure this issue does not fall through the cracks.

Comment: @James please open the bug - saves me from setting up a user account

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is indeed an ambiguity in a partial specialization:

Internally, the allocator uses some metaprogramming (`_Ptr_cat`) to determine if the dtor is to be called on the elements of the vector (or do nothing). This metaprogramming tries to differentiate some cases by using partial specialization. `_Ptr_cat` uses `_Ptr_cat_helper` which is being specialized on the vector's allocator's pointer type -- the vector's `value_type` is `TPointer const* == const float (*)[3]`, so the allocator of the vector has a pointer type `const float(**)[3]`.

When you use `std::vector < const float(*)[3] >`, the error message contains the `[3]` part, whereas using `std::vector < TPoint const* >`, the `[3]` is not displayed o.O

`_Ptr_cat` expects two template arguments of the same type with possibly different c-qualifier, e.g. `float*, float const*`.
Now, the two input types are both `const float (**)[3]`. MSVC resolves them ambiguously to the specializations of `_Ptr_cat_helper`: `Ty**, Ty const**` and/or `Ty**, Ty**`. I verified that by writing a small example which mimics the partial specialization of `_Ptr_cat_helper` (just plain templates, no Std Lib involved).

Yet, I cannot explain why this happens. Strangely, there's no ambiguity when setting up an example using only one specialization parameter -- `const float(**)[3]` is resolved to `Ty const**` with `Ty = float const[3]` as expected.

Thanks to Peter Alexander, I also tried my simple example (2 template parameters) with g++, and it worked as expected, no ambiguity. Maybe this might be a compiler issue?

Let me propose some workarounds:

- If you really want to modify the MSVC standard lib, you could add a specialization `_Ptr_cat_helper < const Ty (**)[3], const Ty (**)[3] >` which fits exactly and resolves the ambiguity. Unfortunately, you have to provide the dimension explicitly (3).
- Do not use arrays *here*. Use `std::array` (available in `tr1` in VS08) or structures or plain pointers (`float const*` instead of `float const[3]`)
- Use a simple wrapper:

  ```
  template < typename T > struct wrapper { T wrapped; }
  std::vector < wrapper < TPoint > const* > m;
  ```

  works fine for me.

Edit: here's the example I used:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

template < typename T1,  typename T2 >
struct Spec
{
    static const char* check() { return "plain"; }
    typedef void Value;
};

#define MAKE_SPEC(ARG0, ARG1) \
template < typename T > \
struct Spec < ARG0, ARG1 > \
{ \
    static const char* check() { return #ARG0 ", " #ARG1; } \
    typedef T Value; \
}

MAKE_SPEC(T**, T**);
MAKE_SPEC(T**, T const**);
// can do more, but need not to..

int main()
{
    typedef Spec < const float(**)[3], const float(**)[3] > MySpec;

    std::cout << MySpec::check() << " -- " << typeid(MySpec :: Value).name();
}
```

Comment: `Maybe this might be a compiler issue` - I'd expect it to be a library issue then. Still +1 for analysis

Comment: As the small example I wrote compiles fine with g++ and not with MSVC, I conclude this is not library issue primarily. I already hit some (confirmed) compiler bugs, and know these are really rare -- therefore trying to formulate it conservatively.

Comment: Huh? The library implementations are totally different... I'm not saying it can't be a compiler issue, but until you, e.g., show GCC+STLPort compiles this, whereas MSVC+STLPort doesn't you have little foundation yet

Comment: Sry, I've obviously not been precise enough: I wrote an example _independent_ from the StdLib which compiles fine on g++ and does not on MSVC. This example mimics what's happening with `_Ptr_cat_helper_`.

Comment: Oh great! Care to share the sample?

Comment: Voilà. g++ compiles and the output is "T const**, T const** -- A3_f" whereas MSVC fails due to ambiguity.

Comment: I like the `struct wrapper` solution. The additional indirection should be eliminated by the compiler's optimizer?

Comment: `metaprogramming to determine if the dtor is to be called` I wonder why 2 levels of indirection `_Ptr_cat_helper<_Ty **, _Ty **>` are necessary to do that. When we have (at least) one level of indirection `Ty*` we know already that no dtor needs to be called!?

Comment: Note that two levels of indirection are not required to reproduce the bug.  A simple pointer-to-array type can demonstrate the issue.  The minimal repro I've used for the bug report is as follows:  https://gist.github.com/3847212.  I would recommend the use of `array<T, N>` here as a workaround (actually, I would recommend the use of `array<T, N>` anywhere you currently use a `T[N]`:  there's really no reason to use ordinary arrays unless you need to do so in order to interoperate with C code).